# What is correct way to generate a sass and ptx from cuda code

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu, nvcc

I am writing a simple cuda kernel where I am measuring the time of the DRAM access and I want to get the ptx and sass code from the cuda code. The device source code is as follows:

```
__global__ void testPtx(int *devBuff,float *devDummy,unsigned int *timeBuff){

    unsigned int temp=0;
    unsigned int start,end;
    volatile unsigned int *tempPtr;
    tempPtr = (volatile unsigned int *)&devBuff[0];

    start = clock64();
    temp=*tempPtr;
    __threadfence();
    end = clock64();
    *devDummy=(float)(1.0/(float)(temp));
    *timeBuff = (unsigned int)(end-start);
  }
```

I am able to generate the sass and ptx file from the source code. But I am confused with the generated files and having some issues which I am going to describe in here.

There seems to be multiple ways to generate the ptx and sass code and reading them. One way to generate the ptx and sass code is to use `--keep` flag in nvcc and it would generate all the intermediate files that contains the ptx and sass of the source code. Another way to generate the files using `-cubin` and `-ptx` option while compiling the source code using `nvcc`. The sass code can be generated using 2 binary tools like `nvdisasm` and using `cuobjdump`. For disassembling `nvdisasm` can only use cubin file whereas `cuobjdump` can use the host binary file.

I am generating the host binary file by using nvcc is `nvcc -O0 -o binfile -m64 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 --verbose --resource-usage sourcefile.cu`. I have tried to put `-cubin` option during the compilation phase but no cubin file gets generated (e.g.`nvcc -O0 -o binfile -m64 -cubin -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 --verbose --resource-usage sourcefile.cu`).  So the method I have taken to generate the cubin file by using nvcc is `nvcc -cubin sourcefile.cu`. However, the `ptx` file can be generated by putting the `-ptx` flag during the main compilation phase (e.g.`nvcc -O0 -o binfile -m64 -ptx -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 --verbose --resource-usage sourcefile.cu`). For disassembling and extracting the `sass`, cubin file that gets generated can be used with nvdisasm and the host binary file (`binfile`) can be used cuobjdump. However, the sass code that gets generated by using `nvcc -cubin sourcefile.cu` and then `nvdisasm -c sourcefile.cubin` is different from the sass code that gets generated by using `cuobjdump` tool (`cuobjdump -sass binfile`). The `sass` code generated from the `nvdisasm` is provided [here](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b3c6) and the code generated by using `cuobjdump` is provided [here](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b3c7). I am confused as why the sass code is different and if I am doing something wrong here. I want to use both the binary tools (preferably more usage of `nvdisasm`) but I want to make sure that the sass code that I am generating corresponds to the source code and not different variation of it. Also I was wondering if I can generate the cubin file while compiling the source code and not generating it separately as I mentioned here. My goal is to generate the cubin file incorporating all the compilation flags (something like `nvcc -O0 -o binfile -m64 -cubin -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 --verbose --resource-usage sourcefile.cu`) and that should correspond to the source and the ptx code. For my work I am using pascal gpu on ubuntu 18.04. Please let me know if I am missing any details or if my post requires more explanation. Thank you.

Comment: You are generating your code with inconsistent arch switches.  Therefore in one case you are looking at sm_30 SASS code and in the other case you are looking at sm_60 SASS code.  Neither method is "incorrect" but it's expected that the SASS from these two will not match.  If you want to generate both PTX and SASS in the same binary, the simplest switch setting is probably by getting rid of all your `gencode` switches and just do something like `-arch=sm_60`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I removed the `gencode` switches and compiled the source code. However, the problem didn't get resolved. I still need to generate the cubin file separately for using nvdisasm (first using `nvcc -cubin sourcefile.cu` and then `nvdisasm -c sourcefile.cubin`) for disassembly which doesn't contain any compilation flag information and so it is still different from sass code generated using `cuobjdump` from the host binary file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only important thing I can see here is to make sure your arch settings match.  Here is what I see:

```
$ cat t39.cu
__global__ void testPtx(int *devBuff,float *devDummy,unsigned int *timeBuff){

    unsigned int temp=0;
    unsigned int start,end;
    volatile unsigned int *tempPtr;
    tempPtr = (volatile unsigned int *)&devBuff[0];

    start = clock64();
    temp=*tempPtr;
    __threadfence();
    end = clock64();
    *devDummy=(float)(1.0/(float)(temp));
    *timeBuff = (unsigned int)(end-start);
  }
$ nvcc -c t39.cu
$ cuobjdump -sass t39.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_52
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_52
                Function : _Z7testPtxPiPfPj
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM52 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM52)"
                                                                                   /* 0x001fc400fec007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20] ;                          /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   CS2R R0, SR_CLOCKLO ;                           /* 0x50c8000005070000 */
        /*0018*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140] ;                         /* 0x4c98078005070002 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ffc00162007f2 */
        /*0028*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x144] ;                         /* 0x4c98078005170003 */
        /*0030*/                   LDG.E.CV R3, [R2] ;                             /* 0xeed4e00000070203 */
        /*0038*/                   MEMBAR.GL.IVALLD ;                              /* 0xef98000000070101 */
                                                                                   /* 0x003fd820e3a00ff6 */
        /*0048*/                   CS2R R2, SR_CLOCKLO ;                           /* 0x50c8000005070002 */
        /*0050*/                   I2F.F32.U32 R3, R3 ;                            /* 0x5cb8000000370a03 */
        /*0058*/                   IADD32I R4, R3, 0x1800000 ;                     /* 0x1c00180000070304 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ff400fda007f6 */
        /*0068*/                   LOP32I.AND R4, R4, 0x7f800000 ;                 /* 0x0407f80000070404 */
        /*0070*/                   ISETP.GT.U32.AND P0, PT, R4, c[0x2][0x0], PT ;  /* 0x4b68038800070407 */
        /*0078*/               @P0 BRA 0xa0 ;                                      /* 0xe24000000200000f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ff400fe0007fd */
        /*0088*/                   CAL 0x120 ;                                     /* 0xe260000009000040 */
        /*0090*/         {         MOV R7, R4 ;                                    /* 0x5c98078000470007 */
        /*0098*/                   BRA 0xd0         }
                                                                                   /* 0xe24000000307000f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fd801fec0071d */
        /*00a8*/                   MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;                               /* 0x5080000000470304 */
        /*00b0*/                   FFMA R5, R3, R4, c[0x2][0x4] ;                  /* 0x5180020800170305 */
        /*00b8*/                   FADD.FTZ R5, -R5, -RZ ;                         /* 0x5c5930000ff70505 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fc400fe2007f6 */
        /*00c8*/                   FFMA R7, R4, R5, R4 ;                           /* 0x5980020000570407 */
        /*00d0*/                   IADD R6, -R0, R2 ;                              /* 0x5c12000000270006 */
        /*00d8*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x148] ;                         /* 0x4c98078005270002 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fc400fe0007f2 */
        /*00e8*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x14c] ;                         /* 0x4c98078005370003 */
        /*00f0*/         {         MOV R4, c[0x0][0x150] ;                         /* 0x4c98078005470004 */
        /*00f8*/                   STG.E [R2], R7         }
                                                                                   /* 0xeedc200000070207 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ffc00fe2007f2 */
        /*0108*/                   MOV R5, c[0x0][0x154] ;                         /* 0x4c98078005570005 */
        /*0110*/                   STG.E [R4], R6 ;                                /* 0xeedc200000070406 */
        /*0118*/                   EXIT ;                                          /* 0xe30000000007000f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fb400fec007f6 */
        /*0128*/                   SHL R4, R3, 0x1 ;                               /* 0x3848000000170304 */
        /*0130*/                   SHR.U32 R4, R4, 0x18 ;                          /* 0x3828000001870404 */
        /*0138*/                   ISETP.NE.U32.AND P0, PT, R4, RZ, PT ;           /* 0x5b6a03800ff70407 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fb400fec007fd */
        /*0148*/               @P0 BRA 0x1c0 ;                                     /* 0xe24000000700000f */
        /*0150*/                   SHL R4, R3, 0x1 ;                               /* 0x3848000000170304 */
        /*0158*/                   ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R4, RZ, PT ;               /* 0x5b6b03800ff70407 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fc801ffa00712 */
        /*0168*/              @!P0 MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;                               /* 0x5080000000480304 */
        /*0170*/              @!P0 RET ;                                           /* 0xe32000000008000f */
        /*0178*/                   FFMA R3, R3, 1.84467440737095516160e+19, RZ ;   /* 0x32807fdf80070303 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fd801fec0071d */
        /*0188*/                   MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;                               /* 0x5080000000470304 */
        /*0190*/                   FFMA R5, R3, R4, c[0x2][0x4] ;                  /* 0x5180020800170305 */
        /*0198*/                   FADD.FTZ R5, -R5, -RZ ;                         /* 0x5c5930000ff70505 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ffc00fe0007f6 */
        /*01a8*/                   FFMA R4, R4, R5, R4 ;                           /* 0x5980020000570404 */
        /*01b0*/         {         FFMA R4, R4, 1.84467440737095516160e+19, RZ ;   /* 0x32807fdf80070404 */
        /*01b8*/                   RET         }
                                                                                   /* 0xe32000000007000f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ff400fda007f6 */
        /*01c8*/                   IADD32I R5, R4, -0xfd ;                         /* 0x1c0ffffff0370405 */
        /*01d0*/                   ISETP.GT.U32.AND P0, PT, R5, 0x1, PT ;          /* 0x3668038000170507 */
        /*01d8*/               @P0 BRA 0x300 ;                                     /* 0xe24000001200000f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fd000fe2007f1 */
        /*01e8*/                   LOP32I.AND R11, R3, 0x7fffff ;                  /* 0x040007fffff7030b */
        /*01f0*/                   MOV32I R10, 0x3 ;                               /* 0x010000000037f00a */
        /*01f8*/                   IADD32I R4, R4, -0xfc ;                         /* 0x1c0ffffff0470404 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001c7400fe0007f2 */
        /*0208*/                   LOP32I.OR R6, R11, 0x3f800000 ;                 /* 0x0423f80000070b06 */
        /*0210*/         {         SHL R10, R10, R5 ;                              /* 0x5c48000000570a0a */
        /*0218*/                   MUFU.RCP R7, R6         }
                                                                                   /* 0x5080000000470607 */
                                                                                   /* 0x381fc400fcc00ff6 */
        /*0228*/                   FFMA R8, R6, R7, c[0x2][0x4] ;                  /* 0x5180038800170608 */
        /*0230*/                   FADD.FTZ R8, -R8, -RZ ;                         /* 0x5c5930000ff70808 */
        /*0238*/                   FFMA.RM R9, R7.reuse, R8.reuse, R7.reuse ;      /* 0x5988038000870709 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fd440fe2007f5 */
        /*0248*/                   FFMA.RP R8, R7, R8, R7 ;                        /* 0x5990038000870708 */
        /*0250*/                   LOP32I.AND R7, R9.reuse, 0x7fffff ;             /* 0x040007fffff70907 */
        /*0258*/                   FSET.NEU.FTZ.AND R8, R9, R8, PT ;               /* 0x588d038000870908 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fc400fca007f1 */
        /*0268*/                   LOP32I.OR R7, R7, 0x800000 ;                    /* 0x0420080000070707 */
        /*0270*/                   IADD R8, -R8, RZ ;                              /* 0x5c1200000ff70808 */
        /*0278*/                   LOP.AND R10, R10, R7 ;                          /* 0x5c47000000770a0a */
                                                                                   /* 0x001fd800fe8407f1 */
        /*0288*/                   LOP3.LUT.NZ P1, RZ, R8, R5.reuse, R7, 0xf8 ;    /* 0x5be103bf805708ff */
        /*0290*/                   SHR.U32 R4, R7, R4 ;                            /* 0x5c28000000470704 */
        /*0298*/                   SHR.U32 R10, R10, R5 ;                          /* 0x5c28000000570a0a */
                                                                                   /* 0x001f8400fd8207f1 */
        /*02a8*/                   LOP.AND.NZ P2, RZ, R10.reuse, 0x2 ;             /* 0x3842300000270aff */
        /*02b0*/                   LOP.AND.NZ P0, RZ, R10, 0x1 ;                   /* 0x3840300000170aff */
        /*02b8*/                   PSETP.OR.AND P1, PT, P1, P2, PT ;               /* 0x509003804107100f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ff400fda007ec */
        /*02c8*/                   ISETP.EQ.U32.AND P2, PT, R11, RZ, PT ;          /* 0x5b6403800ff70b17 */
        /*02d0*/                   PSETP.AND.AND P0, PT, P0, P1, PT ;              /* 0x5090038020070007 */
        /*02d8*/               @P0 IADD32I R4, R4, 0x1 ;                           /* 0x1c00000000100404 */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ffc00fe0007f6 */
        /*02e8*/               @P2 SHL R4, R4, 0x1 ;                               /* 0x3848000000120404 */
        /*02f0*/         {         LOP3.LUT R4, R4, c[0x2][0x8], R3, 0xf8 ;        /* 0x02f8018800270404 */
        /*02f8*/                   RET         }
                                                                                   /* 0xe32000000007000f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001ffc01ffe0071d */
        /*0308*/                   MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;                               /* 0x5080000000470304 */
        /*0310*/                   RET ;                                           /* 0xe32000000007000f */
        /*0318*/                   BRA 0x318 ;                                     /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
                                                                                   /* 0x001f8000fc0007e0 */
        /*0328*/                   NOP;                                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0330*/                   NOP;                                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0338*/                   NOP;                                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                ..........



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_52
code version = [7,2]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$ nvcc -cubin t39.cu
$ nvdisasm -c t39.cubin
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_TEXMODE_UNIFIED EF_CUDA_64BIT_ADDRESS EF_CUDA_SM52 EF_CUDA_VIRTUAL_SM(EF_CUDA_SM52)"
        .elftype        @"ET_EXEC"


//--------------------- .text._Z7testPtxPiPfPj    --------------------------
        .section        .text._Z7testPtxPiPfPj,"ax",@progbits
        .sectioninfo    @"SHI_REGISTERS=12"
        .align  32
        .global         _Z7testPtxPiPfPj
        .type           _Z7testPtxPiPfPj,@function
        .size           _Z7testPtxPiPfPj,(.L_34 - _Z7testPtxPiPfPj)
        .other          _Z7testPtxPiPfPj,@"STO_CUDA_ENTRY STV_DEFAULT"
_Z7testPtxPiPfPj:
.text._Z7testPtxPiPfPj:
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20] ;
        /*0010*/                   CS2R R0, SR_CLOCKLO ;
        /*0018*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140] ;
        /*0028*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x144] ;
        /*0030*/                   LDG.E.CV R3, [R2] ;
        /*0038*/                   MEMBAR.GL.IVALLD ;
        /*0048*/                   CS2R R2, SR_CLOCKLO ;
        /*0050*/                   I2F.F32.U32 R3, R3 ;
        /*0058*/                   IADD32I R4, R3, 0x1800000 ;
        /*0068*/                   LOP32I.AND R4, R4, 0x7f800000 ;
        /*0070*/                   ISETP.GT.U32.AND P0, PT, R4, c[0x2][0x0], PT ;
        /*0078*/               @P0 BRA `(.L_1) ;
        /*0088*/                   CAL `($_Z7testPtxPiPfPj$__cuda_sm20_rcp_rn_f32_slowpath) ;
        /*0090*/         {         MOV R7, R4 ;
        /*0098*/                   BRA `(.L_2)         }
.L_1:
        /*00a8*/                   MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;
        /*00b0*/                   FFMA R5, R3, R4, c[0x2][0x4] ;
        /*00b8*/                   FADD.FTZ R5, -R5, -RZ ;
        /*00c8*/                   FFMA R7, R4, R5, R4 ;
.L_2:
        /*00d0*/                   IADD R6, -R0, R2 ;
        /*00d8*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x148] ;
        /*00e8*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x14c] ;
        /*00f0*/         {         MOV R4, c[0x0][0x150] ;
        /*00f8*/                   STG.E [R2], R7         }
        /*0108*/                   MOV R5, c[0x0][0x154] ;
        /*0110*/                   STG.E [R4], R6 ;
        /*0118*/                   EXIT ;
        .weak           $_Z7testPtxPiPfPj$__cuda_sm20_rcp_rn_f32_slowpath
        .type           $_Z7testPtxPiPfPj$__cuda_sm20_rcp_rn_f32_slowpath,@function
        .size           $_Z7testPtxPiPfPj$__cuda_sm20_rcp_rn_f32_slowpath,(.L_34 - $_Z7testPtxPiPfPj$__cuda_sm20_rcp_rn_f32_slowpath)
$_Z7testPtxPiPfPj$__cuda_sm20_rcp_rn_f32_slowpath:
        /*0128*/                   SHL R4, R3, 0x1 ;
        /*0130*/                   SHR.U32 R4, R4, 0x18 ;
        /*0138*/                   ISETP.NE.U32.AND P0, PT, R4, RZ, PT ;
        /*0148*/               @P0 BRA `(.L_3) ;
        /*0150*/                   SHL R4, R3, 0x1 ;
        /*0158*/                   ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R4, RZ, PT ;
        /*0168*/              @!P0 MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;
        /*0170*/              @!P0 RET ;
        /*0178*/                   FFMA R3, R3, 1.84467440737095516160e+19, RZ ;
        /*0188*/                   MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;
        /*0190*/                   FFMA R5, R3, R4, c[0x2][0x4] ;
        /*0198*/                   FADD.FTZ R5, -R5, -RZ ;
        /*01a8*/                   FFMA R4, R4, R5, R4 ;
        /*01b0*/         {         FFMA R4, R4, 1.84467440737095516160e+19, RZ ;
        /*01b8*/                   RET         }
.L_3:
        /*01c8*/                   IADD32I R5, R4, -0xfd ;
        /*01d0*/                   ISETP.GT.U32.AND P0, PT, R5, 0x1, PT ;
        /*01d8*/               @P0 BRA `(.L_4) ;
        /*01e8*/                   LOP32I.AND R11, R3, 0x7fffff ;
        /*01f0*/                   MOV32I R10, 0x3 ;
        /*01f8*/                   IADD32I R4, R4, -0xfc ;
        /*0208*/                   LOP32I.OR R6, R11, 0x3f800000 ;
        /*0210*/         {         SHL R10, R10, R5 ;
        /*0218*/                   MUFU.RCP R7, R6         }
        /*0228*/                   FFMA R8, R6, R7, c[0x2][0x4] ;
        /*0230*/                   FADD.FTZ R8, -R8, -RZ ;
        /*0238*/                   FFMA.RM R9, R7.reuse, R8.reuse, R7.reuse ;
        /*0248*/                   FFMA.RP R8, R7, R8, R7 ;
        /*0250*/                   LOP32I.AND R7, R9.reuse, 0x7fffff ;
        /*0258*/                   FSET.NEU.FTZ.AND R8, R9, R8, PT ;
        /*0268*/                   LOP32I.OR R7, R7, 0x800000 ;
        /*0270*/                   IADD R8, -R8, RZ ;
        /*0278*/                   LOP.AND R10, R10, R7 ;
        /*0288*/                   LOP3.LUT.NZ P1, RZ, R8, R5.reuse, R7, 0xf8 ;
        /*0290*/                   SHR.U32 R4, R7, R4 ;
        /*0298*/                   SHR.U32 R10, R10, R5 ;
        /*02a8*/                   LOP.AND.NZ P2, RZ, R10.reuse, 0x2 ;
        /*02b0*/                   LOP.AND.NZ P0, RZ, R10, 0x1 ;
        /*02b8*/                   PSETP.OR.AND P1, PT, P1, P2, PT ;
        /*02c8*/                   ISETP.EQ.U32.AND P2, PT, R11, RZ, PT ;
        /*02d0*/                   PSETP.AND.AND P0, PT, P0, P1, PT ;
        /*02d8*/               @P0 IADD32I R4, R4, 0x1 ;
        /*02e8*/               @P2 SHL R4, R4, 0x1 ;
        /*02f0*/         {         LOP3.LUT R4, R4, c[0x2][0x8], R3, 0xf8 ;
        /*02f8*/                   RET         }
.L_4:
        /*0308*/                   MUFU.RCP R4, R3 ;
        /*0310*/                   RET ;
.L_5:
        /*0318*/                   BRA `(.L_5) ;
.L_34:
$
```

Those two sets of SASS are the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was actually able to generate the sass code during the main compilation phase and not separately. However, the -arch flag is important as you mentioned. I have just a following question based on your answer. In the sass code the program exits at address 0118. However, I am confused about the purpose of the following instructions after 0118. Using nvdisasm I have annotated the sass code with source code line numbers. It shows that the function exits at 0118 and there are no source code for the following instructions. Then what is the purpose of it and what it does?